# Less restrictive search returns fewer results (specific case?)

Tags: bug, search

Search results on SO seem to behave strangely, at least in this case:

- Searching for "VB6DEP" returns no results
- Searching for "VB6DEP.ini" returns three results

I would have expected the first search to at least return the results of the second, since it was less restrictive.

Is this due to the period character? Some flaw?

**Case 1:**

> [image]

**Case 2:**

> [image]

Comment: You can use `VB6DEP*`

Comment: @JonClements, is it because SO search engine search for complete words?Can such info be added to [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), people are likely to be used to google search, `*` in middle makes sense, but at the end has to be explained. In google it seems like it's always `*a* *b*` (for `a b` query) and I think one has to use `-` to narrow search to exclude longer words.

Comment: @Sinatr - It's there, but could be clearer: *"Use wildcard searches to broaden results; add an asterisk (`*`) anywhere in the word, like `encour*` or `Ex*nge`"* Note the `*` at the end of `encour`.

Comment: @tripleee On Google it's similar (although you can't see it for this specific query): the "less restrictive" `overflo` returns way fewer results than the "more restrictive" `overflow`. Although Google does handle punctuation differently.

Comment: @Dukeling `overflo` IS the more restrictive term, since it presumably occurs much less frequently. Google does some kind of word-identification parsing which makes it seem that is the way to think about it.

Comment: @Dukeling and you may have hit the nail on the head; this depends on how SO handles the period. Given that it is universally used as a separator in filenames, some "special" consideration in search would seem appropriate.

Comment: @DaveInCaz Giving `.` special consideration would make searching for something like `java.lang.String` more difficult (it's probably not going to mean much for that specific example, but there are certainly cases where it's more significant).

Comment: @DaveInCaz Technically speaking, all occurances of 'overflow' are also occurances of 'overflo', so it should not be more restrictive. E.g. imagine calling `myString.indexOf('overflo')`, you would expect it to find occurances of 'overflo' and also occurances of 'overflow' right? Since 'overflow' starts with 'overflo'. But SO search is doing smart stuff with whitespace probably which is why it works out differently.